# Looks like MSVS 11.0 Beta spoiled a MSVS 10.0 installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, visual-studio-2012

I ran into compilation problems with my MSVS 10 after installing MSVS 11Beta. Now, when I compile my C# Projects in MSVS 10 (Projects created in MSVS 10; Target framework: 3.5), I get errors `MSB4216`, `MSB4028` with following text in output window:

```
1>Task "GenerateResource" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(EmbeddedResource.Type)' == 'Resx' and '%(EmbeddedResource.GenerateResource)' != 'false' and '$(GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime)' != 'CLR2') was evaluated as ('Resx' == 'Resx' and '' != 'false' and 'CLR2' != 'CLR2').
1>Task "GenerateResource"
1>  Launching task "GenerateResource" from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" in an external task host with a runtime of "CLR2" and a process architecture of "x86".
1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2199,5): error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because we could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR2" and architecture "x86".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NetFX 4.0 Tools\MSBuildTaskHost.exe" exists.
1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2217,7): error MSB4028: The "GenerateResource" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "FilesWritten" parameter. Object does not match target type.
1>Done executing task "GenerateResource" -- FAILED.
```

How can I fix these errors?

***EDIT:***

1. Mentioned file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NetFX 4.0 Tools\MSBuildTaskHost.exe" exists.
2. C++ projects are compling without problems.
3. Reinstalling VS10 doesn't solve the problem.
4. This is `GenerateResource` task, that must compile resx-file, but generates an exception:

`<!-- But we can't use those parameters if we're targeting 3.5, since we're using the 3.5 task -->`

```
<GenerateResource
    Sources="@(EmbeddedResource)"
    UseSourcePath="$(UseSourcePath)"
    References="@(ReferencePath)"
    AdditionalInputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects)"
    NeverLockTypeAssemblies="$(GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies)"
    StateFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectFile).GenerateResource.Cache"
    StronglyTypedClassName="%(EmbeddedResource.StronglyTypedClassName)"
    StronglyTypedFileName="%(EmbeddedResource.StronglyTypedFileName)"
    StronglyTypedLanguage="%(EmbeddedResource.StronglyTypedLanguage)"
    StronglyTypedNamespace="%(EmbeddedResource.StronglyTypedNamespace)"
    StronglyTypedManifestPrefix="%(EmbeddedResource.StronglyTypedManifestPrefix)"
    PublicClass="%(EmbeddedResource.PublicClass)"
    OutputResources="@(EmbeddedResource->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(ManifestResourceName).resources')"
    MSBuildRuntime="$(GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime)"
    MSBuildArchitecture="$(GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture)"
    Condition="'%(EmbeddedResource.Type)' == 'Resx' and '%(EmbeddedResource.GenerateResource)' != 'false' and '$(GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime)' == 'CLR2'">
```

1. I tried to [debug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio.aspx) MSBuild script (`.csproj`). Just before the fatal `GenerateResource` task I checked all the *properties* and *items*. There was nothing about "8.0A" but only about "7.0A"

Comment: Did you check that the required file exists per the error? "Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NetFX 4.0 Tools\MSBuildTaskHost.exe" exists."

Comment: @Chris - Yes this file exists, and I can see in procmon log, that app  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NetFX 4.0 Tools\MSBuildTaskHost.exe" started and was performing some actions.

Comment: It could be a path issue.  VS11 may have set a path that is overriding a path your build script assumes and is using the wrong version of files or dll's.  Check your paths.

Comment: @MystereMan - Thanks. Do you mean VS11 changed my `Microsoft.Common.targets`?

Comment: @Loom, no I mean your path.  Do you not know what your filesystem path is?

Comment: Do you have any environment variables that specify SDK 8.0A? The VC10 environment queries `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A` to find its SDK path - is that still pointing to 7.0A or 8 now?

Comment: @Rup - Thanks. Unfortunately, this path is still pointing to 7.0A

Comment: Have you tried simply reinstalling VS10?

Comment: @EdS. - Yes, I have. It didn't help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an ugly way to fix the problem: renaming folder `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A"`. I hate to accept this answer.

Comment: @LuisFilipe - Rename it to any meaningless name that couldn't be found  by old name (I renamed "v8.0A" to "_v8.0A")

Comment: +1 for a solution at least. The real answer is to track down why MSBuild is trying to use that for .NET 4, but I'm out of suggestions where you can look.

Comment: +1 from me for solution.. dont have time to reinstall the VS10

Comment: @AnarchistGeek - Thank you. Actually, reinstalling the VS10 didn't solve the problem

Comment: +1 also hid same issue that popped up on my previously working box with 2013 Update 2 on a machine that's never had 2010 (or 2012). No, no RCA done whatsoever. (command line build using MSBuild 4.0 [not 12], still had similar problems building inside VS [which is 12]). Yes, extremely unprofessional :(

Answer (score 8):

How long is your username?

It seems that there is a bug when the username is 20 characters long. If your username is 19 characters or less it works fine.

I have opened an issue on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758772/generateresource-fails-for-net-3-5-application-when-net-4-5-has-been-installed).

**Edit:**
Have you tried setting the environment variable `DisableOutOfProcTaskHost` to true as suggested in the connect issue, that worked for me.

Comment: Cool. It's a kind of magic. But my username consist of 13 letters.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot test 'DisableOutOfProcTaskHost' workaround, because MSVS 11 Beta expired and has been uninstalled. Current VS 2012 Express does not reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A similar questin was asked on the MSDN forums.  Did you reboot after installing VS11?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/7d955d96-ff73-47d3-8830-85ea321eb4ab

Comment: No, I installed VS11 a month ago

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurred for me on my TFS 2010 build server after installing VS2010 and then installing .NET Framework 4.5. This allowed me to build .NET 4.5 projects but any VS2008 project targeting CLR2 (.NET 2.0 -3.5) I attempted to build would return the error. None of the suggestions on the handful of sites talking about this issue worked.

1. Rebooting - Did not fix the issue
2. Setting DisableOutOfProcTaskHost = true in an environment variable and also within the project file - Did not fix the issue
3. Username of my build account was already less than 20 characters
4. Renaming windows SDK folder - N/A since I did not have VS2012 and the 8.0A SDK installed... just .NET framework 4.5.

In any case, to fix this I uninstalled .NET 4.5, repaired VS2010, and then rebooted the build server. Now I am able to build VS2008 and VS2010 projects with no issues.

Luckily I no longer need to build .NET 4.5 projects as that team decided to go back to .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible fix is to change the target framework of your projects to .Net 4.0. It's not always a solution, but it certainly is a possibility if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me: Removing the bin  and obj folder for problematic folders and restarting the solution

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I received that error message when trying to build a solution on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine. The way to resolve the error for me was to right-click on the project, choose properties, then go to the Build tab. In here I changed the "Platform target" from "Any CPU" to "x86". HTH

Answer (score 0):

Setting Setting `DisableOutOfProcTaskHost = true` in an environment variable worked for me.