# MSBuildTaskHost.exe has stopped working

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am Facing problem with visual studio 2010, when i am trying to build the application it gives me  "MSBuildTaskHost.exe has stopped working" error.

[image]

Comment: Check your event logs for the associated error and provide those details here too

Comment: allen i have checked the event logs it is showing me fetal error message, "MSBuildTaskHost.exe" has stopped working, and it is providing me the debugger.

Comment: So there is no further details in the logs? no exception etc/

Comment: Even after re installation of Visual Studio the error remains, it happened because one of the software deleted the shared files, and MSBuild file was one of them .MSBuild file is required to compile the program, so i've re installed the operating system, and thats it the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Although quite old I'll answer this question as it still shows up at first place in Google. In my situation the problem was caused by a Visual Studio 2012 installation. A dirty way to fix it is to rename/remove the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A` as described in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247337/looks-like-msvs-11-0-beta-spoiled-a-msvs-10-0-installation)